# Erratic Search Results in Large Library

Tags: search-results, sharepoint-library

We have a large library, approx. 2,500,000, items which forms the backend of our CRM.

Some users are reporting that when they search the library they are not seeing all the results they should be seeing. I have checked that they have permission to see the missing items.

The only explanation I can come up with is that the size of the list is causing the inconsistent results but I don't understand why it appears only to be affecting some users.

Can anyone think of any other explanation?

Answer (score 0):

If you have checked permissions then I would check if the parameter
trimduplicates=false